# unable to install 'XML' package dependency for 'pmml' on Ubuntu

Tags: r, cran, pmml

I was trying to install the 'pmml' package in R using the install.packages('') option as well as from source. But keep getting errors both ways.

Trying from R

```
install.packages('pmml',dependencies=T)
Cannot find xml2-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/XML’
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘pmml’
* removing ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/pmml’
```

Trying from source

```
> install.packages('pmml_1.4.2.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘pmml’
* removing ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/pmml’
Warning message:
In install.packages("pmml_1.4.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘pmml_1.4.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Trying using R CMD INSTALL

```
 % R CMD INSTALL pmml_1.4.2.tar.gz                         
* installing to library ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘pmml’
* removing ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/pmml’
```

I have also tried install the xml library for R using these same methods, but keep getting similar errors like

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/PepperBoy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/XML’
```

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu? If so, `apt-get install libxml2-dev` first and then try to reinstall from CRAN. You need to install the `libxml2` library.

Comment: @nicola, This is fantastic. Worked. thanks
If you could add this as an answer, would be nice.

Comment: Glad it helped. Added an answer.

Comment: @nicola, ohh can't accept the answer. not enough reputation. Upvoted though. Will come back after a few days and accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually you can accept (and you did indeed), but you can't upvote :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the system library `libxm2-dev` to install the `XML` package (on which `pmml` depends). So, if you are on Debian or Ubuntu, just install it through:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

and then proceed with the R packages installation. Be careful to check the `SystemRequirements` section in the home page of any R package you want to install (for `XML`, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html)).